# How to test a mongo connection in laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query, laravel-5.7

I am using laravel 5.7 and mongo db(v1.5.3 stable).
I am trying to test connection from laravel to db but everytime I am getting successfull connection even I am providing wrong credentials.

I have tried by the following ways:

**Jessengers**

```
        $arrMongo = [];

        if(true == DB::connection('mongodb')) {
            $arrMongo = array(
                'status'=>true,
                'message' => 'Mongo connection OK'
            );
        }else{
            $arrMongo = array(
                'status'=>false,
                'message' => 'Mongo connection failed'
            );
        }
```

**Normal PHP way**

```
$server = "mongodb://google.com:27017/university";
        $c = new \MongoDB\Client( $server );
        if($c->connected)
            echo "Connected successfully";
        else
            echo "Connection failed";
```

I am never getting as connection failed while testing with wrong credentials.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: You should run composer dump-autoload. Also clear the cache and try again. if situation is same then double check the documentation at https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Comment: @SaifurRehman I tried the ways you suggested but still it is showing connection is OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel only connects to the database when it needs something from the database.

You may opt for getting the list of databases inside try/catch block as follow:

```
try {
    DB::connection()->getMongoClient()->listDatabases();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```